Timefold / Optaplanner variable listener concurreny issues
I have a running solution where we implemented a sort of multi-chained model using Timefold. In our model, each planning entity has several planning variables. These variables are chained using variable listeners to ensure that when one variable changes, the corresponding shadow variables of the entity and all other relevant entities are updated accordingly.
However, we have encountered a problem. When the afterVariableChanged() method is called by the framework, and we start changing the values, one or more entities sometimes get their values changed by the framework before we exit the afterVariableChanged method. This unexpected behavior makes the model unstable, as we cannot always guarantee a rollback to the exact same state.
To address this, we inserted a synchronized lock when entering afterVariableChanged(). This solved part of the problem as long as we run on a single CPU. However, we now occasionally encounter deadlocks when both solving and calling the SolverManager for status, as there seem to be other locks inside the framework that conflict with our synchronized lock.
Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a better way to ensure a stable state while working on the model in afterVariableChanged() without using synchronized or other locks? Additionally, is there a way to check before calling the SolverManager for status to ensure it will not deadlock?
Thanks in advance for your help!

What version of Timefold are you running with?

Hi we are at 1.10.0, but saw this occationally also on previous versions.

A variable listener runs in a ScoreDirector on the working Solution of that ScoreDirector. A single thread has that working solution to itself, even with multithreaded solving.
Unless planning cloning somehow messes up (fix with @DeepPlanningClone), it's impossible to deadlock on synchronization as everything comes from the same thread. There is no need for the synchronized keyword in variable listener calls.

It seems then that we could then have another problem, so i willl need to investigate a bit further to figure out how exactly where the changes comes from, as we have no other code that tries to manipulation the entity variables, and the changes are valid values from the valueranges. I would assume the planningentities are deepcloned by default, but will look at that to.  Can we also expect the return call with BestSoltionConsumer and FinalBestSolutionConsuer to be safe, as we also here experienced that the solution changed values while the consumer handled the reponse solution.

Planning entities and the planning solution are planning cloned by default.
Beyond that, there's a bit of logic that classes referencing the planning entities are planning cloned if we can easily detect them doing that.

Would be nice if it would be clear which classes are planning cloned. Created this issue: https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/866

We did some more test, there are two threads entering the variablelistener, ( pool-5-thread-1 and http-nio-9191-exec-2) the second start before the first is finished, so it seems that as the UI is polling it request a solution and a score and hence that thread also goes through at the same time as the solver thread, hence creating  situation from the variable listener point of view, that seems as if two enitities are changed at the same time ? is this expected or should we clone the solution and the the score by handing it to another solver so they dont interfere with each other.

We also double checked the entity instances, it turned out they are not cloned by default, but if we add @DeepPlanningClone then they are indeed cloned as expected.

@Christian Can you share an isolated gist.github.com of the classes (potentially obfuscated) that has the issue? I'd like to understand why the default cloner didn't automatically planning clone that class.

Hi, it turned out to work as intended. It was a transactional scope issue, where the solvers best solution consumer in one thread would sometimes not be in sync with other threads accessing the same entities through JPA from different entitymanagers. A rewrite of the transactional managemet handled the problem
